# Fix input errors and continuation issues in validation form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form that will not show errors when the wrong text is input and won't continue on to the next step after selecting next.

Here is how it's supposed to function (scroll to bottom): http://infinite-woodland-5276.herokuapp.com/forms-validation.html

Here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j31qm806/3/

```
init.push(function() {
  $('#wizard-forms').pixelWizard({
    onFinish: function() {
      // Disable changing step. To enable changing step just call   this.unfreeze()
    this.freeze();
  }
});
$('#wizard-forms .wizard-prev-step-btn').on('click', function() {
  $('#wizard-forms').pixelWizard('prevStep');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: what i saw is... jquery library is missing that is why nothing is happening...

Comment: @OmasuPlus The library has been updated but shows another error

Comment: @user2680614 https://jsfiddle.net/j31qm806/4/ - fiddle with jquery enabled properly. Now your first line is `init.push(...` but you haven't defined any object called "init". What's it supposed to be?

Comment: @ADyson Look here http://infinite-woodland-5276.herokuapp.com/forms-validation.html (scroll to the bottom) . It's supposed to go to step 2.

Comment: @user2680614 yes but you have a more fundamental problem than that. You're invoking some object called "init" without ever defining it. You need to sort that or none of your code will run. I'm asking you if you know what "init" is supposed to be - should it be from a library reference, or have you missed some of your own code out? I presume you've noticed the JS error in the console

Comment: @ADyson That's the problem - I don't understand what's missing. Why does it work in the demo but not in the fiddle?

Comment: compare the libraries / plugins used by the demo to yours. They've probably got something extra loaded. You can View Source on their page to see any external dependencies.

Comment: @ADyson I've added the only missing library to no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121564/discussion-between-user2680614-and-adyson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed

```
var init = [];
```

from the start of your code. This is present right at the top of the source of the demo you linked to.

You've also missed

```
window.PixelAdmin.start(init);
```

from the end of your code.

Both those statements need to be outside any kind of `window.onload` / `$(document.ready()` type function - but everything else should be inside it.

See a working example at https://jsfiddle.net/j31qm806/21/

Comment: I've placed it in the file and still nothing. Would you mind trying it yourself in fiddle to see the issue as well

Comment: what error do you get now? And link me to your latest fiddle please

Comment: haven't you checked the browser console for errors? There's an obvious error right there. Bootstrap not working due to requiring jQuery. Your references are added in the wrong order. https://jsfiddle.net/j31qm806/18/ sorts that out. Now the problem still exists, because you're not initialising the pixelAdmin stuff, or referencing pixelAdmin either

Comment: now see https://jsfiddle.net/j31qm806/21/ which fixes it. You also weren't declaring init outside the document.ready function (because of the way the fiddle was set up) or initialising the pixelAdmin. All it was doing was dumping loads of stuff into the init variable, but not using it for anything. Answer updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably forgot to include libraries needed by your script.

In fact, the object "init", is not defined :

```
init.push(function() {
   $('#wizard-forms').pixelWizard({
    onFinish: function() {
      // Disable changing step. To enable changing step just call       this.unfreeze()
this.freeze();
   }
 });
```

So, you must make sure that you've included all the libraries and/or plugins needed by the script.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've added all of the necessary libraries. The only function that is undefined is what you posted but this is all that was provided. What's making the form in fiddle to not function while the other on the website i provided does